# How to add dist-tag to npm package in private registry?

Tags: javascript, npm, publish, gem-fury

I have a private Gemfury registry that I'm publishing npm packages to.

I want to add distribution tags to my packages (as described here: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/dist-tag).

My npm config registry is set to a proxy that allows me to install from my private registry and the public npm registry. I can also publish to my private registry correctly.

When I run `npm view` on my private package, I am able to see all the info I would expect for my package.

When I attempt to use any of the `npm dist-tag` commands, I run into issues. I simply get a `404 Not Found` error from npm.

I run:

```
npm dist-tag ls my-private-package-name
```

and receive:

```
npm ERR! dist-tag ls Couldn't get dist-tag data for my-private-package-name
npm ERR! Darwin 16.4.0
npm ERR! argv "/Users/me/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.6/bin/node" "/Users/me/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.6/bin/npm" "dist-tag" "ls" "my-private-package-name"
npm ERR! node v4.2.6
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.12
npm ERR! code E404

npm ERR! 404 Not Found : MyPriVaTeGemfuryToKEn
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 'MyPriVaTeGemfuryToKEn' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 Your package name is not valid, because
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  1. name can no longer contain capital letters
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
```

Nope, that's not a typo. This is weird. And it happens with all of the `dist-tag` commands. The error message is somehow using my private Gemfury token as the package name? But only kind of? Because the first line of the error seems to be correct. This could just be a weird error message, but the real issue is that I can't seem to use any `dist-tag` commands for a package in my private registry. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify which registry npm looks at

`npm dist-tag --registry=https://example.com ls my-private-package-name`